# Creating Jenkins pipelines build from jenkins operator

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-operator

We are migrating from `Jenkins Master/Slave` installation to `Kubernetes deployment` using `Jenkins` operator from https://jenkinsci.github.io/kubernetes-operator/docs/getting-started/latest/

This is a snippet from our initial `jenkinsfile`

```
   pipeline {
    agent {
        label ('jenkins-slave')        
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Cloud Authentication') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'mygcpproject-8e16', variable: 'key')]) {
                        sh """
                        cat ${key} > mykeys.json
                        chmod 400 mykeys.json
                        """ 
                    }

                 sh """
            gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=mykeys.json
            curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/\$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
              """             
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Deploy the resource/app  and service to the cluster ') {
        steps {
            script {
                
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}/create") {
                    def jsonObj;
                    jsonObj = readJSON file: 'parameters.json'
                    sh "any command"
```

Now since we are moving to `Jenkins running as kubernetes pods` , what should be our value for `agent` inside the `pipeline`

```
        pipeline {
          agent {
            label ('jenkins-slave')
```

Any suggestions or reference to any documentation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `Jenkins` in `k8s` agents can be define two ways. One option is directly from `yaml` in `Jenkinsfile`. Second way is to include pod template from repository where you store your `Jenkins` pipeline configuration file.

Please refer to [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-declarative-pipeline) part of `k8s` plugin documentation for more detail instruction.